# what happens when we update a newer version of our already existing app in google play store

Tags: android, google-play

i have uploaded an updated version of my app in google play store, immediately after doing so i went to play store to check it, so it shows the older version. if any user who has not yet downloaded my app will he get the updated version of the app or the initial version of the app?
any ideas please suggest as i am a complete newbie to android.
i have tried finding posts related to it but no results so guys please help.
should i deactivate the older version of the app, what happens if i do so or i do not.

Comment: you need to wait a bit for the update to propagate & show up.

Comment: Until the updated version propagates to the servers, new users (as well as existing users) will continue to see the currently available version (_not the updated version_). Existing users will be notified of an update if they have option **Notifications** options checked in the Play Store app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you upload a new app, google has to check it first. They don't want any virusses in it.

So after the checks have been completed, you app will be shown in the Play Store. Everybody who downloads your app before the checks have been completed, will download the older version. However, when the checks have been completed, everybody who has turned on the auto-update for apps, will download your new version automatically 
Just upload, an wait a couple of hours!

Comment: thank u ... it helped... but my database changes didnt get reflected in the update version plus my google map crashes